# How to add style/css to a simple jQuery accordion?

Tags: jquery, css

Please check this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v5eV3/

I wonder how to add style to that acordion, especially when it is active.

On hover I managed, but the problem is when it is active.

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cur_stus;

    //close all on default
    $('#accordion dd').hide();
    $('#accordion dt').attr('stus', '');

    //open default data
    $('#accordion dd:eq(0)').slideDown();
    $('#accordion dt:eq(0)').attr('stus', 'active');

    $('#accordion dt').click(function(){
        cur_stus = $(this).attr('stus');
        if(cur_stus != "active")
        {
            //reset everthing - content and attribute
            $('#accordion dd').slideUp();
            $('#accordion dt').attr('stus', '');

            //then open the clicked data
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).attr('stus', 'active');
        }
        //Remove else part if do not want to close the current opened data
        else
        {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
            $(this).attr('stus', '');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: active is not a class. active is like hover in CSS:

`:active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` jQuery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cur_stus;

    //close all on default
    $('#accordion dd').hide();
    $('#accordion dt').attr('stus', '');

    //open default data
    $('#accordion dd:eq(0)').slideDown();
    $('#accordion dt:eq(0)').attr('stus', 'active');
    $('#accordion dt:eq(0)').addClass('active');

    $('#accordion dt').click(function(){
        cur_stus = $(this).attr('stus');
        if(cur_stus != "active")
        {
            //reset everthing - content and attribute
            $('#accordion dd').slideUp();
            $('#accordion dt').attr('stus', '');
            $('#accordion dt').removeClass('active');

            //then open the clicked data
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).attr('stus', 'active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        //Remove else part if do not want to close the current opened data
        else
        {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
            $(this).attr('stus', '');
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v5eV3/2/